# Android Custom ArrayAdapter NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

Currently trying to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` for a list view:

```
public class FilesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] _objects;

public FilesArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this._objects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_layout, null); 
    }

    String string = _objects[position];

    if(string != null){
        TextView fNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);

        if(fNameView != null){
            fNameView.setText(string);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

This is the layout `R.layout.entry_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am binding the list on the main activity however it's throwing a `NullPointerException` this Line:

```
TextView fNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
```

The text view exists within the mentioned layout and there are no problem with the layout file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getView()` method you must do:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_layout, null);
```

Comment: These mistakes just happen, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_layout, null);
```

as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_layout, null); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_layout, null);
}

String string = _objects[position];

if(string != null){
    TextView fNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);

    if(fNameView != null){
        fNameView.setText(string);
    }
}

return convertView;
```

}